# Twisted. Error callback on spawnProcess's processExited

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.internet

I am running a command with Twisted's ProcessProtocol.

I am using the documentation scaffold and I have several events like inConnectionLost, connectionMade, etc

But when the process finish this event is triggered:

```
def processExited(self, reason):
    print 'processExited, status %d' % (reason.value.exitCode,)
    if reason.value.exitCode == 0:
        print 'SUCCESS!!!'
    else:
        print 'ERROR!!!'
        raise RuntimeError, 'some custom error message'
```

As you can see I am trying to raise the error to catch it in an upper level.
I am wrapping the command call with a deferred like this:

```
def success_pipeline(success):
    log.debug('The pipeline has finished correctly.')

def failure_pipeline(error, command):
    log.debug('The pipeline failed...')

command = CommandProtocol()
reactor.spawnProcess(command, application_bin, command_arguments, {})

d = Deferred()
d.addCallback(success_pipeline)
d.addErrback(failure_pipeline, command)
return d
```

But, although the command failed (I manually mistyped the arguments) it's always going into the success callback. The reason.value.exitCode is 1 so in bash it's confirmed it failed.

So how can I catch an errback to custom handle the failure?

Answer (score 0):

You can hand over the deferred object to `CommandProtocol` and let it call `callback` and `errback` on it from there.

It is documented at the bottom of this page:
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html